# How do I present an alarm to a user, even when my application is inactive?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

I want to make an app which will let you set an alarm inside my iPhone app, then have it be activated even though my app is not running.

How would I implement this?

Comment: Xcode is just an IDE - you probably mean iOS and/or CocoaTouch ?

Answer (score 7):

You want to use `UILocalNotification`. A couple things to note before you dive in:

1. It's only available on iOS4 and up.
2. NSDate is a pain in the ass, and it's the only option for scheduling

With that said, you can begin:

```
 UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

 notif.alertBody = @"This is a Local Notification";
 NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
 notif.fireDate = [date addTimeInterval:600];// fire the notification in ten minutes
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
 [notif release];
```

If you need any more help, just comment :)

Comment: i don't want to display the message .can i play some sound instead of alert

Comment: Nope. The alert is the only way I know of to show something based on time when your app is closed. You can set the UILocalNotification to play a sound with `notif.soundName`.

Comment: when i launch the app the notification cannot be shown but after closing only it displayed.tell me why?

Comment: If a notification fires while the app is open, it is not shown. It is passed to the method below. You can choose to do whatever you want with it there. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveLocalNotification:

Comment: If it worked, it's good etiquette to mark my answer as correct :)

Comment: without show the notification can i play some sound like ringtone.

Comment: Can we use it silently?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

in .h

```
int *currentTime;
```

in .m

```
-(void)startTimer {

     NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateCurrentTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void)updateCurrentTime {

      currentTime ++;
      if (currentTime == userDefinedTime) {

            // Time is up

      }

}
```

Comment: i want to run eventhough the app not running